# Maintaining map dimensions after using Colorize

Tags: image-processing, geography

I am trying to beautify a map by using `Colorize` as demonstrated in the [*Mathematica* documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Colorize.html). First, I import a shapefile from [DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/) for France which contains polygons for the country, its regions and departments.

```
mapdata = Import["http://gadm.org/data/shp/FRA_adm.zip", "Data"];
```

I then extract the region data and (poorly) place a bounding region around the map:

```
Graphics[Rectangle[{-6, 41}, {9.7, 51.5}]];
Graphics@{EdgeForm[Thick], FaceForm[White], ("Geometry" /. mapdata[[2]])};
t1 = Show[%%, %]
```

I can then `Colorize`

```
t2 = Colorize[MorphologicalComponents[t1, CornerNeighbors -> False], ColorFunction -> "LightTerrain"]
```

which gives me the following `Image` (note, it is not a `Graphic`)

[image: France in terrestrial colors]

I'd now like to take the department information and lay it over the colored regional map

```
t3 = Show[Graphics@{Black, EdgeForm[Thin], FaceForm[], ("Geometry" /. mapdata[[1]])}]
```

[image]

However the `MorphologicalComponents` function rescaled the regional map, preventing me from overlapping t2 and t3 above.

Is there a way to get the same or similar effect as obtained through `MorphologicalComponents` and `Colorize` without losing the x,y coordinate data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem comes from rasterization by `MorphologicalComponents`. Maybe you could avoid it at the first place.

```
mapdata = Import["http://gadm.org/data/shp/FRA_adm.zip", "Data"];

regiondata = "Geometry" /. mapdata[[2]];
departdata = "Geometry" /. mapdata[[1]];

regionNum = Length@regiondata

t1 = Graphics@{
   Rectangle[{-6, 41}, {9.7, 51.5}],
   EdgeForm[Thick],
   MapIndexed[{ColorData["LightTerrain"][
       Rescale[#2[[1]], {1, regionNum}]], #1} &, regiondata]
   }

t3 = Graphics@{Black, EdgeForm[Thin], FaceForm[], departdata}

Show[{t1, t3}]
```

[image]

Comment: Why not `{RGBColor[0, 0.33, 0.643], Rectangle[{-6, 41}, {-0.77, 51.5}], White, Rectangle[{-0.77, 41}, {4.47, 51.5}],  RGBColor[0.98, 0.235, 0.196], Rectangle[{4.47, 41}, {9.7, 51.5}]}`?

Comment: @wxffles That is a good call. But the background is not the topic concerned in the question, nor it is a hard job, so I'll just let it be what it's in the question. ps. I just found [some interesting historical evolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_France#Design) about the proportion of the 3 bars's widths.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Thanks:)

Comment: @wxffles I concur - the Black background is from my attempts to use `MorphologicalComponents` and I'm happy to have a solution that avoids that problem.  Thanks Silvia.

Comment: @bobthechemist You're welcome. Glad I can help.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is using rectangle at the beginning. Use `Background -> Black` instead:

```
t1 = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], 
   FaceForm[White], ("Geometry" /. mapdata[[2]])}, Background -> Black, ImageSize -> 600];

t2 = Colorize[MorphologicalComponents[t1, CornerNeighbors -> False], 
  ColorFunction -> "LightTerrain"];

t3 = Show[Graphics@{Black, EdgeForm[Thin], 
    FaceForm[], ("Geometry" /. mapdata[[1]])}, ImageSize -> 600];

Overlay[{t2, t3}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice solution however the final object rendered isn't in the original coordinate system.  The next step of my project is to overlay the GPS coordinates of a trip log, so I'm hoping to find a solution that maintains the original (lat-long) data.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution proceeds similarly to Vitaliy's, but preserves the coordinates of France's departments:

```
france = Import["http://gadm.org/data/shp/FRA_adm.zip", "Data"];
provinces = Colorize[MorphologicalComponents[
                     Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], FaceForm[White],
                               "Geometry" /. france[[2]]}, Background -> Black], 
                     CornerNeighbors -> False], ColorFunction -> "LightTerrain"];

Graphics[{Thin, ("Geometry" /. france[[1]]) /. Polygon -> Line}, 
         Prolog -> {Texture[provinces], 
                    Polygon[ImageScaled /@ {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
                            VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]
```

[image: the departments of France]

The black background is a bit unseemly to me, though. I don't know how to replace it with a different color.